# PyGlet Shape Following The Mouse

Tags: python, geometry, cursor, pyglet

So I try to make a "game" with PyGlet:

This is my code:

```
import pyglet
from pyglet import shapes

window = pyglet.window.Window(800, 600, "PyGlet Window")
circle = shapes.Circle(x = 100, y = 100, radius = 13, color=(255, 255, 255))

def callback(dt):
    pass

pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(callback, 0.5)

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    circle.draw()

pyglet.app.run()
```

How to make the circle follow the mouse? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement the `on_mouse_motion` event (see [Working with the mouse](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/programming_guide/mouse.html)) and change the position of the shape (see [pyglet.shapes](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/shapes.html)):

```py
@window.event
def on_mouse_motion(x, y, dx, dy):
    circle.x = x
    circle.y = y
```

Comment: I knew about `on_mouse_motion()` event, but i didn't knew about `.x`/`.y`, but thanks anyway.